# javascript : module vs global function - what is a difference?

Tags: javascript, function, module

What is the main difference between a module like this

```
var MODULE = (function () {
   var my = {},
      privateVariable = 1;

   function privateMethod() {}

   my.moduleProperty = 1;
   my.moduleMethod = function () {};

   return my;
}());
```

and a simple function like this

```
function MODULE_Func() {
   var my = {},
      privateVariable = 1;

   function privateMethod() {}

   my.moduleProperty = 1;
   my.moduleMethod = function () {};

   return my;
};
var MODULE = MODULE_Func();
```

I read an article about modules and in it an author describes a module's advantages as: "the module maintains private internal state using the closure of the anonymous function."

i.e, I think he means that 'privateVariable ' and 'privateMethod' is internal for the module and not acceptable from outside. But in the simple function 'privateVariable ' and 'privateMethod' are also internal and not acceptable from outside. The only difference I can see is that the module is a anonimous function so it: 1) doesn't pollute a global state 2)you can't invoke the module twice.

But the author describes a module pattern as a great thing but I can't see for what. And because you can't invoke the module twice, you can't have more than one instances of modules, I think in many cases it is even a disadvantages.

Comment: It's the same thing. You just give the temporary a name in the second case

Comment: Assume that `my.moduleMethod` makes use of the variable `privateVariable`.  The first example has no problem remembering that `privateVariable == 1` during subsequent calls (perhaps occurring much later, for example as part of a browser event handler).  But the second example will not have any idea what privateVariable is.  That's what is meant by "maintains private internal state".

Comment: " But the second example will not have any idea what privateVariable is." - can you explain this please?

Answer (score 0):

> But the author describes a module pattern as a great thing but I can't see for what

Well, you've said it yourself: *1) doesn't pollute a global state 2) you can't invoke the module twice*. Those are advantages if you want them.

> And because you can't invoke the module twice, you can't have more than one instances of modules, I think in many cases it is even a disadvantages.

Those modules are *static*. Indeed, they should not have internal *state* but only local (internal) variables, e.g. for helper functions.

In cases where you need multiple instances, don't use a singleton-like module. Use a constructor ("class") instead, like in your second example. You might however still use a module as a namespace for your class.

Answer (score -1):

the difference is that the first one

var MODULE = (function(){})();

**`MODULE` refers to whatever an the anonymous function being executed will return. if it returns nothing then **MODULE** will be set to undefined. the function being executed is an IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression), [More info here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). It executes on page load since **MODULE** is referred by the global window.

and the second is a function MODULE_func(){}, **`MODULE_FUNC`** is the name of the function itself, this function is now a property of the global window meaning that it can be referred by the global window as so `window.MODULE_func(){};`, the other can be referred as well but note the difference, the other is an anonymous function without a name and has **TWO** referrers. This one has a name and one referrer..

- var MODULE = (function(){})();
   can be referred by

  window.MODULE;
  MODULE;
- function MODULE_func(){}
   can be referred by

  window.MODULE_func; **ONLY**

Comment: "the MODULE is a reference to an anonymous function WITHOUT A NAME." -- I think MODULE is a reference to an object returned by an anonimous function but not the function itself.

Comment: No, the first `MODULE` is not a reference to the function. It has been executed! Btw, you can refer to the second with just `MODULE_func` (no `window.`) as well.

Comment: also, I can't refer to MODULE_func as window.MODULE_func() because I get 'undefined', but I can refer as MODULE_func()

Comment: @user3649516, the module is a reference to an anonymous function.

Comment: @Bergi, you're right, it can be executed with just MODULE_func, but i was showing the OP that it is referred to by the window as well.

Comment: @Hawk: user3649516 is right. Read http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @Bergi, got it..i tested an you were right as well..that it's been executed and module refers to a function that has already returned hence undefined or whatever it would return..

Comment: hope that's a better answer for users that land here in the future..hehe

Comment: Thanks for the update, but that part about "*TWO referrers*" and the "*ONLY*" is still wrong.

Comment: please do the honors @Bergi